# What happens if you upvote your own answer/question?

Tags: support, voting

Just curious, what would happen if you voted up your own question or answer? I don't want to test this out in case I lose reputation or something.

Comment: Hey, always nice to see new faces on the site.  You should join us in chat!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The system prevents you from casting an upvote on your own questions or answers by way of a message telling you that you can't. There is no rep penalty invoked or anything, since it's very plausible for users to click that button, either accidentally or out of curiosity.

[image]